How to Use AND Operator with OR Condition in Supabase Query?
I'm working on a query in Supabase where I need to select specific columns from a table based on multiple conditions. Specifically, I need to select columns a, b, and c from a table where column e is equal to a specific value (e = e) and at least one of the columns (a, b, or c) is equal to another value. Let's call it g.
SELECT a,b,c

FROM table

WHERE e = e

AND (a = g OR b = g OR c = g);

I'm hoping for something similar to the below:
supabase
    .from('table')
    .select('a, b, c')
    .eq('e', e)
    .then(({ data, error }) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching data:', error.message);
        } else {
            console.log('Data:', data);
        }
    });

But additionally with the AND operator query above.
However, this only handles the condition where e = e. How can I incorporate the additional condition where at least one of a, b, or c is equal to g using the AND operator in Supabase?
I've tried using the .or() method within the .eq() method, but I haven't been successful. Can anyone guide me on how to structure this query properly?
Thank you.

According documentation,  you can chain filter conditions and by default they will be chained as AND.  And here is syntax for .or().
Putting it all together:
supabase
    .from('table')
    .select('a, b, c')
    .eq('e', e)
    .or('a.eq.g, b.eq.g, c.eq.g')
    .then(({ data, error }) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching data:', error.message);
        } else {
            console.log('Data:', data);
        }
    });



To use the AND operator with an OR condition in a Supabase query, you can structure your query using parentheses to ensure proper grouping of conditions,
You should need to follow below syntax...
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE (condition1 AND (condition2 OR condition3));

Or in code you can modify like this,
supabase
  .from('table')
  .select('a, b, c')
  .eq('e', e)
  .or(`a.eq.${g}`, `b.eq.${g}`, `c.eq.${g}`)
  .then(({ data, error }) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching data:', error.message);
    } else {
      console.log('Data:', data);
    }
  });

In above code i add

.or(a.eq.${g}, b.eq.${g}, c.eq.${g})

It checks if at least one of columns a, b, or c is equal to the value g.
That's it, i hope I'm able to solve your query.
